# Add counter to for each loop

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, counter

I've been unable to figure out how to add a counter to the below `for each` loop, so that when an entire column of formulas has been completed the loop moves to the next column. All of the calculations are correctly occurring, but all in the same column. Thanks for any suggestions.

```
Sub Test()
Dim SrchRng1 As Range, cell1 As Range
Dim SrchRng2 As Range, cell2 As Range

Dim lr As Long
lr = Sheets("sheet1").Cells(Rows.count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
Set SrchRng1 = Sheets("sheet1").Range("B3:B95")

Dim lc As Long
lc = Sheets("sheet2").Cells(3, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set SrchRng2 = Sheets("sheet2").Range("A3:AC3")

Dim lrr As Long
lrr = Sheets("sheet2").Cells(Rows.count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

Dim c As Long
c = 0

For Each cell1 In SrchRng1
    For Each cell2 In SrchRng2

        If cell1.Value = cell2.Value Then
            c = 31
            For r = 4 To 100
                  Cells(r, c).FormulaR1C1 = "=sheet1!" & cell1.Offset(, 1).Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1) & "*" & cell2.Offset(1, 0).Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1) & ""
            Next r
            c = c + 1
        End If
    Next cell2
Next cell1
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are always resetting c to 31 each time. move the c= 31 out of the inner loop, to just under the first for statement. Like this:

```
For Each cell1 In SrchRng1
    c = 31
    For Each cell2 In SrchRng2

        If cell1.Value = cell2.Value Then

             For r = 4 To 100
                  Cells(r, c).FormulaR1C1 = "=sheet1!" & cell1.Offset(, 1).Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1) & "*" & cell2.Offset(1, 0).Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1) & ""
            Next r
            c = c + 1
        End If
   Next cell2
Next cell1
```

Comment: Thanks! I put it outside of both `for each` loops and it worked! I've been staring at this macro too long.

Comment: @user3290799 Glad I could help.